# ElasticSearch/NEST: Determine if Mapping already exists

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, mapping, nest

I'm using the [NEST client](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/) to access my ElasticSearch indexes/mappings. I'm trying to determine if a mapping already exists, and if not create a new mapping. There's a method for `IndexExistsAsync()` but there doesn't appear to be a `MappingExistsAsync()` method. `GetMappingAsync()` returns an `IGetMappingResponse` which has a boolean `IsValid`, that I thought I might be able to check, but calling `GetMappingAsync()` just throws an exception if the mapping doesn't exist. I can just check if an exception is thrown and create the mapping, but is there a better way of handling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The issue was that I had set up the client to throw exceptions on failure instead of allowing the `IsValid` to be what determines success.

```
var connectionPool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(node);
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool)
    .BasicAuthentication(username, password)
    .DisableDirectStreaming()
    .PrettyJson();
    //.ThrowExceptions(); <-- This line had to be commented out.
```

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't you use

```
TypeExists defined on the interface IElasticClient
```

Instead?

I mean if the type exists the mapping of that type also exists.